# Problema en lectura de archivo ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Alguna idea de porque da este error? `No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /lib/oc/` tengo varios archivos txt en esa carpeta mi codigo lee cualquier archivo .txt y posteriormente lo utilizo para analizarlo.

```
  Dir.foreach('/lib/oc/')  do |item| 
   next unless File.extname(item) == '.txt'
    next if File.directory? item
    file = File.read(item)
   File.delete(item) if File.exist?(item)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es el uso de `/` al inicio, pues eso indica una ruta **absoluta** y al parecer estás buscando una ruta **relativa** (razón por la que no encuentra el directorio); para arreglarlo simplemente elimina la `/` inicial:

```
Dir.foreach('lib/oc/') do |item| 
  # ...
end
```

Si lo que buscas es ejecutar el código dentro de tu aplicación de *rails* entonces podrías utilizar `Rails.root` para obtener el directorio raíz de tu aplicación y luego agregar `/lib/oc/`:

```
Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/lib/oc/") do |item| 
  # ...
end
```

Comment: esta es mi ruta windows de la carpeta `C:\Users\jonathan zambano\Desktop\test\vinoteca2\orden_compra\lib\oc ` y el error que me arroja ahora es que no existe `aaa.txt` pero si existe `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - aaa.txt` al final me indica que lo leyo